# fgets hangs in while loop

Tags: c, fgets

SOLVED: fixed when closing infile before opening qfile.

I'm trying to process two files in c. For the first file I read in lines then process the strings. I'm using fgets, however when the while loop is in the last iteration it just hangs. I have:

```
//Not complete code. While loop is all that is in method that uses the file. 
//File I/O error checking is in place, does not assume there is always a file in argv[2]
FILE *infile;
FILE *qfile;

struct tree{
    char *name;
    char *id;
    char *permission;
    struct tree *next;
 };
 struct tree *root;
 struct tree *current;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 //proper file i/o error checking in place 
  infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if(infile != NULL)
     fill();//process first file
   qfile = fopen(argv[2], "r");
   if(qfile != NULL)
      find();//process second file
   }

void fill(void){
   char buffer[256];
   int first = 1;
   while(fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),infile) != NULL)
   {
      if(first && buffer[0] == "X")
      {
         root = (struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
         current = root;
         process(buffer, current);
         first = 0;
      }
      else if(buffer[0] == 'F')//siblings
      {
         current->next = (struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
         current = current->next;
         process(buffer, current);
      }
}

void process(char buffer[], struct tree *current)
{
    char *left;
    char *right;
    left = buffer;
    right = buffer;
    while(*left == 'F')
    {
            left++;
    }
    while(*right != ':')
    {
            right++;/*
            if(*right == ' ')
                    continue;*/

    }

    //assign name to current node
    current->name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(right-left));
    strncpy(current->name, left, right-left);
    left = right + 1;
    while(*right != '=')
    {
            right++;
    }

    //assign property to current node
    current->property = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(right-left));
    strncpy(current->property, left, right-left);

    left = right + 1;
    while(oright != '\n')
    t = (struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
                    current = root;
                    process(buffer, current);
                    //root->name = buffer;

                    first = 0;
            }
            else if(buffer[0] == 'F')//siblings
            {
                    current->next = (struct tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
                    current = current->next;
                    process(buffer, current);

    {       right++;}

    //assign value to current node
    current->value = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(right-left));
    strncpy(current->value, left, right-left);
    printf("Name =%s\nProperty=%s\nValue=%s\n", current->name,current->property,current->value);
    }
```

It goes through the entire file and then just hangs in the while loop. This only processes the first file. When I don't include a second file(process stdin) it doesn't hang. When it does hang it checks all the conditionals and stops at the bottom of the loop. The last line of the file is a newline character by itself.

What could be causing the loop to hang? Using 64-bit linux.

EDIT: Proper file I/O checking in place. Not complete code as I narrowed problem down to while loop in fill(). fill() only processes first file. Second file is processed by find(), a different method. Problem is with first file only. First file only used in fill().

EDIT2: posted complete code, print statements are for tracking.
Sorry about all the confusion.

Comment: infile  (file pointer) is used uninitialized in the posted code

Comment: It (`fgets`) should only "hang" if waiting for input. If this input is from an interactive STDIN/terminal, make sure to *close the stream* - e.g. press ^D (this sends EOF) when feeding data from a terminal. Without the EOF the steam will just wait expecting more input.

Comment: input is from a file, sorry forgot to include in above code but infile is initialized.

Comment: Suspect something between OP's true code and this post significantly differ.  Also, what file names are used?

Comment: Are you testing argv[1] before using it, i.e. Double check the location, spelling etc on the input to argv[1] (i.e. is the directory and filename correct?).  Also, look at the content of the input file.  Is it a text file, with normal ascii text, or is it a binary file? (I can see you are opening it as a text, for read, but is it a valid text file?)

Comment: @chux - Just saw your post.  That's a good possibility.

Comment: if input is processed it is always text file.

Comment: @ryyker I'm wondering about the posted `find()` function.  Is that `fill()`?

Comment: no `find()` only processes second file. `fill()` only processes first file. Problem was narrowed down to while loop in `fill()`

Comment: 1) `while(*right != ':')` should be `while(*right != ':' && *right != '\0')`.  2) `strncpy(current->name, left, right-left);` potential problem as is does not always `\0` terminate the destination.

Comment: @LHBD *Bad* form to delete your question after so many have applied so much work.  Better undelete, post your own solution, accept it and add an edit to your question the solution you found.

Comment: NOTE: I rolled back to what _appeared_ to be the version showing what the question was about. Correct me if I'm wrong (there were ten versions)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize the question had deleted. My bad. Thanks for the rollback.

Comment: I've deleted the "[SOLVED]" from the title. The way to indicate that your problem has been solved is to accept an answer. If none of the existing answers solve the problem, post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: [Reconsider your use of `strncpy()`.](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html)

Comment: @KeithThompson couldn't answer my own question. Done now thanks.And thanks for the insight on strncpy().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close first file before opening second file in main.

Answer (score 0):

First of all always check I/O

first check if there are enough number of arguments to your program since you use `argv[1]` 
then check whether you successfully opened the file

e.g.

```
if ( --argc )
{
  infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if ( infile != NULL )
  {
    // do your fgets stuff
    fclose(infile);
  }
}
```

Comment: I/O error checking in place. didn't want to include long code. Sorry, If its best then I could paste entire code. Thought snippets where problems come from would be sufficient, but I should've mentioned that. Thanks for answering though.

Answer (score 0):

OP uses `fill()`, which reads `infile` both after `infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");` and `qfile = fopen(argv[2], "r");`

OP needs to pass stream pointer to `fill()` function.

Also OP calls `find()` instead of expected `fill()`.  Is this typo in posting or *the* problmem?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  FILE *infile;
  FILE *qfile;
 //proper file i/o error checking in place 
  infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if(infile != NULL)
     fill(infile);//process first file
  FILE *qfile;
  qfile = fopen(argv[2], "r");
  if(qfile != NULL)
    fill(qfile);//process second file
  }
}

void fill(FILE *f){
   char buffer[256];
   while((fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),f)) != NULL)
   {
      if(first time && line isn't empty or newline)initialize struct;
      else if(not first time && line isn't empty or newline)connect structs;
   }
}
```

Comment: infile and qfile are both in global scope,  since main executes first changes to infile and qfile including file opening are passed to other functions because of global scope. Or am I completely off base?

Comment: @LHBD, When you do `qfile = fopen(argv[2], "r"); if(qfile != NULL) find();`, how does `fill()` know to use `qfile` and not to use `infile` again?

Comment: fill() only uses infile. find() only uses qfile. Each function runs once. Each text file is processed only once.

Comment: @LHBD, What are the file names?

Comment: @LHBD  Suspect we'll need to see the real `fill()`.

Comment: they vary but are .txt or custom extension .a3 but all files have ascii text only.

Comment: Guess I'll have to wait for the filenames and the `fill()` details.

Comment: `fill()` completely posted. Filenames are parktemp.txt, parkkeep.a3

Comment: @LHBD Concerned about `while(*right != '\n')` because it is _not_ guaranteed the buffer ends with a `\n`, especially if its the last line.  GTG - more later.